# Datadog NTP Integration - Failed to Get Clock Offset from Any NTP Host

Tags: web, server, integration, monitoring, ntp

I'm currently facing an issue with Datadog's NTP integration, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. The error message I'm encountering is as follows:
**from the apps section in Datadog**
`Instance #ntp:3c427a42a, 70bbf8[ERROR]: Failed to get clock offset from any ntp host`

On my server when i run
`datadog-agent status`
**output**
`ntp --- Instance ID: ntp:3c427a42a70bbf8 [ERROR] Configuration Source: file:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/ntp.d/conf.yaml.default Total Runs: 1 Metric Samples: Last Run: 0, Total: 0 Events: Last Run: 0, Total: 0 Service Checks: Last Run: 1, Total: 1 Average Execution Time : 1ms Last Execution Date : 2024-01-18 04:53:47 UTC (1705553627000) Last Successful Execution Date : Never Error: Failed to get clock offset from any ntp host No traceback`

i have tried severally commands and instruction as suggested by chatgtp and other post on the net but the error was still there.
i also uninstall and install a new Datadog-agent but still, that did not solve the problem